# R Igraph kamada-kawai 4.1.2 vs. 3.6.3 problem

Tags: r, graph, layout, igraph, kamada-kawai

We found (what we think is) a very strange problem.
We have a graph (845 nodes; 1086 edges). We load it as a GML string (works fine):

```
library("igraph")
g = read_graph("goo.gml", format = "gml")  

gsize(g)
[1] 1086

gorder(g)
[1] 845
```

When we request node coordinates for a kamada-kawai layout (`layout.kamada.kawai(g)`),
we get a perfect graph in R/Igraph 3.6.3, but a garbage graph in R/Igraph 4.1.2. Both versions are running on Linux.

Below are the plots of both the 3.6.3 (good) and the 4.1.2 (bad) solutions:

3.6.3 (good):
[image]

4.1.2 (bad):
[image: 4.1.2 (bad)]

Another weird thing is that when we add just a single node with a single edge to this network and rerun the solution, it renders fine in both 3.6.3 and 4.1.2.

Another weird thing is that we render a lot of graphs and this is the only one we have yet found that seems to misbehave under 4.1.2. (Needless to say that it is exactly this particular graph that we need a lot :-( )

Any ideas?

Comment: 3.6.3 and 4.1.2 sound like versions of R. Can you also report `packageVersion("igraph")`? (It would be best to report all relevant bits of `sessionInfo()` run on each platform.

Comment: We did some experiments and the furthest we can go back for a properly working version is R: 4.0.5 (March, 2021); Igraph  1.3.0.

The version we are currently running (generates bad KK coordinates): R: 4.1.2; Igraph: 1.3.5

Comment: >sessionInfo():

`R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C`

Comment: Can you install earlier versions of `igraph` (see `remotes::install_version`) and find the exact package-version transition point from working to not working? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Bizarre!! I tested all igraph versions 1.3.0 - 1.3.5 (installed with remotes::install_version() as you suggested) with R 4.2.1 and now everything works fine in each of these versions. Previously I did remove.packages('igraph) and install.packages('igraph') several times and it made no difference whatsoever. 
I don't understand this (just reinstall igraph' a few times?? -- a colleague of mine working independently observed the exact same thing), but I guess I can work with this.

Comment: OK!  Voting to close as "not reproducible" http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/misc/chesterfield.html

Comment: As far as we can tell, it appears that the error occurs in the production version of igraph 1.3.5 (install.packages('igraph')), but does not occur in the development version of igraph 1.3.5 (remotes::install_version('igraph', '1.3.5')).
(fine to close, but this is very(!) reproducible)

Comment: BTW, Ben, can you add 'kamada-kawai' as a keyword? I am way too 'junior' to do this.

Also, thanks for your help. You helped us debug this and at least find a way around the problem.

Comment: OK, I see there are 45 questions with "kamada-kawai" on SO, so that seems reasonable.

Comment: @BenBolker IMO the "kamada-kawai" tag is not very useful, and probably shouldn't exist at all. This is really an igraph question, so that's the tag that need to be (and is) present.

Comment: @ReneReitsma If you can consistently reproduce the problem, please open an issue in the igraph bug tracker at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/, and add a _minimal_ reproducible example. Also include complete information about your system, including the versions of R, igraph and your OS, CPU type, and your compiler.

Comment: The workaround is to set initial coordinates manually.  The KK layout will not always converge, see https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/383 and https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/963 However, I improved the behaviour significantly for R/igraph 1.3.2 and I am surprised to see that it still occurs.